# Conditional macros

Tags: macros, conditionals, brackets

**Goal:** I would like to have a macro that substitutes different commands depending in whether in displayed math mode or not. In particular, it should generate fixed-size angular brackets in text lines, `\langle ... \rangle`, but variable-size in displayed math, `\left<...\right>`.

**Motivation:** The macro should be universal because mathematical expressions may be often moved between displayed and non-displayed expressions (I write a textbook, edit it, re-edit etc). It would be a source of typos if I needed to change the expression code each time when moving it from or to displayed math. The above example with the angular brackets is the standard notation for averaging in the physics literature.

**The first attempt** is in the MWE below. It works for inline math, but fails to substitute  correctly when in the display mode. LaTeX reacts with "Missing \right. inserted" or "Bad math environment delimiter" depending on the usage of `$$` or `\[` and `\]`, respectively. Compilation in the batch mode generates an output with the correct size of left bracket, but wrong right one. This result does not depend on the usage of \def or \newcommand. It is tested to be the same for square brackets `[...]`.

**The system:** Mac OS 12.7.2., LaTeX: <This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>>

**Now an MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\def \la{\ifinner \langle \else \left< \fi }
\def \ra{\ifinner \rangle \else \right> \fi }
\begin{document}
The macros work in the text line: $\la \int \Omega_n^2 dt \ra$, 
but do not in the displayed math. Obviously, the 
false text is not expanded properly, but why?  
\[
\la \int \Omega_n^2 dt \ra 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifinner` basically never does anything useful in tex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: note that `\left<...\right>` will have worse horizontal spacing then `\langle....\rangle` even if the normal size delimiters are chosen.

Comment: `\def \la{\TextOrMath{\langle}{\left<}}`
`\def \ra{\TextOrMath{\rangle}{\right>}}`

Comment: I'd use a different syntax for this, if you used a normal argument (e.g., `\newcommand\lara[1]{...}`) you can then use `\mathchoice` for this.

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please EDIT your question and add some motivation for your question? E.g. why do you want this, and what will you achieve once you have it? Etc. Thank you

Comment: @yannisl `\TextOrMath` doesn't help here, this question isn't about distinguishing text mode from maths mode, but inline maths from displayed.

Comment: @\Skillmon The question was about a problem with expansion and `\TextOrMath`  solves this, and works well in both modes. Mathchoice is another way to solve it also as you mentioned. Perhaps if the OP expands a bit we can understand better the question.

Comment: @yannisl no, the question is not about an expansion issue, the question is about detecting whether we're in inline maths (in which case `\langle...\rangle` should be used), or display maths (in which case `\left\langle...\right\rangle` should be used). `\TextOrMath` is an `\ifmmode` test, so distinguishes between text mode and maths mode and can't be used for OP's purpose.

Comment: @yannisl no, `\TextOrMath` is a choice of text mode or math mode,the OP wants a choice between displaystyle and text style math (which isn't possible really)

Comment: I would use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from mathtools which will give you `\foo{xxx}` making `<xxx>` with control over the size of < used.

Comment: your definitions give errors as `\ifinner` is false in the display math (it is not false in all display math, it would be true in an `align`)  but then it starts `\left<` and after that the math is set with `\ifinner` true and so the test at the right takes the other branch. The `\ifinner` on the right will never be false.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle one could hook into every display-maths environment and set a conditional. Something like `\newif\ifmydisplay\AddToHook{env/equation/begin}{\mydisplaytrue}`, and then use `\ifmydisplay` instead of `\ifinner`, but I'm not sure whether it's worth the hassle over `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

Comment: @Skillmon true but you'd have to make the conditional false in all nested non display constructs such as arrays or fractions so you'd end up redefining everything.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle only if nested non-display constructs should look different from display (in which case we could simply use `\mathchoice` anyway after collecting the contents as an argument). So "needs clarification".

Comment: @Skillmon yes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advise against using this approach. It won't generally do “the right thing”.

Anyway, since the customer is always right, you can exploit `amsmath` `\if@display` conditional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\la}{\if@display\left\fi\langle}
\newcommand{\ra}{\if@display\right\fi\rangle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The macros work in the text line: $\la \int \Omega_n^2 \, dt \ra$,
and also in displayed math
\[
\la \int \Omega_n^2 \, dt \ra
\]
\begin{align}
I=\la \int \Omega_n^2 \, dt \ra
\end{align}
\begin{gather}
I=\la \int \Omega_n^2 \, dt \ra
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg! It works. I just wonder, how does the integral symbol know if it is inline or displayed? Is the method the same?

Comment: @VKphysicist That's essentially built in TeX. See the rules in Appendix G of the TeXbook.

Answer (score 3):

`\ifinner` tests a low level aspect of TeX's state but it  basically never does anything useful in tex in relation to any document level elements.

Here, in `\la` it tests **True** in inline math and **False** in `\[` but would test true in `amsmath` display environments such as `gather` or `align` as they enter displaystyle via
`$\displaystyle display math$` not
`$$ display math$$`

However the test is always **True** in `\ra` as either the expression was already inner, or if `\ifinner` was false at the start `\la` will execute `\left<`  which sets `\ifinner` true as all math within the left-right pair is in inner mode. So you never execute the matching `\right`.

Also `\left..\right` should be avoided in cases where stretching is not needed as it affects the horizontal spacing.

A more robust mechanism is provided by `mathtools` which also corrects for the horizontal spacing from left-right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\test{\relax\ifinner T\else F\fi}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ang\langle\rangle

\begin{document}

a $\test  \ang{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}  \ang[\big]{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}$

\[
\test \ang{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}  \ang*{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}  \ang[\Big]{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}
\]

\begin{equation}
  \test \ang{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}  \ang*{\int \Omega_n^2 dt} \ang[\Big]{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
  \test \ang{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}  \ang*{\int \Omega_n^2 dt} \ang[\Big]{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David! The explanation of the error is very clear and it is nicely illustrated with your '\test'. It looks suitable to use '\ang*' as a universal command, but it puts also '\left...\right' in inline math, which I would like to avoid (please, correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: see last line `\ang` does not use left/right \ang* does

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that \ang{X} is equivalent to \langle X \rangle, while \ang*{X} is  \left\langle X \right\rangle? If so, the commands for inline and displayed math need to be different, without or with the star, respectively.

Comment: @VKphysicist except it fixes the horizontal spacing (like mleftright package) but as shown above I wouldn't use the * form often, it's often too big, the `\Big` version is big enough on the last row. But yes it doesn't do quite what you ask (as tex doesn't really support exactly what you asked for)

Comment: Thank you anyway. I learned a lot from this conversation.

Answer (score 1):

TeX switches the typesetting-mode to "inner" when encountering a `\left`-delimiter in math mode.

So it seems the issue is about expanding `\ifinner` at the right moment in time.

You can use `\expanded` for having the `\ifinner`-tests evaluated before any more typesetting and hereby switching the typesetting-mode takes place:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\la{\ifinner\else\expandafter\left\fi\langle}%
\newcommand*\ra{\ifinner\else\expandafter\right\fi\rangle}%
\begin{document}
The macros work in the text line: $\la \int \Omega_n^2 dt \ra$, 
and also do work in the displayed math.
\[%
\expanded{\la \unexpanded{\int \Omega_n^2 dt} \ra}
\]%
\end{document}
```

In some situations the circumstance that this way `\la` and `\ra` and thus `\langle`/`\left\langle` and `\rangle`/`\right\rangle` get expanded completely might be a problem.

You can have a macro wrap these into `\unexpanded` as well:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\inangle[1]{%
  \expanded{%
    \ifinner\else\unexpanded{\left}\fi\unexpanded{\langle}%
    \unexpanded{#1}%
    \ifinner\else\unexpanded{\right}\fi\unexpanded{\rangle}%
  }%
}%
\begin{document}
The macros work in the text line: $\inangle{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}$, 
and also do work in the displayed math.
\[\inangle{\int \Omega_n^2 dt}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Caveat:**

**As already noted by [David Carlisle in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706625/118714), these approaches in any case fail with LaTeX-environments where stuff actually is not typeset in display mode but is typeset in inline mode with display style selected via `\displaystyle`.**